# Moved javascript to separate file, ajax calls are giving error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In trying to cleanup my code base, I moved all of my javascript from script tags to their own javascript file. After doing that, all of my ajax calls are failing.

Here's the javascript, this is EXACTLY how it was in the *.cshtml file, excluding the script tags:

```
$(function () {
    $("#weightList").change(function () {
        var weight = $("#weightList").val();
        var conference = $("#conference").val();

        $("#wrestlerAList").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#wrestlerBList").prop('disabled', true);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetByWeight", "Wrestler")',
            data: {
                weight: weight
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                var wrestlers = "<option></option>";

                $.each(data, function (i, wrestler) {
                    wrestlers += "<option value='" + wrestler.Value + "'>" + wrestler.Text + "</option>";
                });

                $("#wrestlerAList").html(wrestlers);
                $("#wrestlerBList").html(wrestlers);

                $("#wrestlerAList").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#wrestlerBList").prop('disabled', false);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("An error occurred retrieving the wrestlers for this weight.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I've tried removing the "$(function () {...});" but that didn't work. Is there other syntax required when the javascript is not directly on the cshtml page?

Edit: I'm loading my javascript file at the very end of the cshtml file, right before the closing  tag.

Also, I'm getting a 404 back. If the code stayed the same, why would it now be getting a 404?

Comment: what exactly the error is?

Comment: Do the `jquery` is being loaded before this script?

Comment: @VMAtm I load my javascript page at the very end of the cshtml file right before the "</body>" tag. Also, looks like it's returning a 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 url: '@Url.Action("GetByWeight", "Wrestler")',
```

that line needs to be rendered on a cshtml page.  it doesnt get processed in a .js file.

Comment: Thanks, I was just going to edit my question and ask if that was allowed in a javascript file. Thanks for answering!

Comment: lol that was very ambitious of you to think that @Url.Action will work even if  placed in a java script file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you are setting the ajax url

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetByWeight", "Wrestler")'
```

The ASP.NET MVC tag helper @Url.Action() will not work inside a .js file.

You could place the url in a hidden form field and read it from there.

Place this somewhere in the .cshtml preferably outside of any forms so it is not posted back in the form for any reason.

```
@Html.Hidden("ServiceUrl", Url.Action("GetByWeight", "Wrestler"))
```

Then use the code below to set the jQuery ajax url

```
url: $('#ServiceUrl').val(),
```

Comment: not sure if it actually caused my issue, but I originally added this INSIDE the form tag, and it did NOT work (just returned the entire html contents of the page), as soon as I moved it outside the form tag, it worked. Wish I could accept your answer also!